# How can I make the object to rotate back when releasing a key press?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

```
private void Update()
{
if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.R))
        {
           objectToScale.transform.Rotate(Vector3.up, rotationSpeed * Time.deltaTime);
        }

        if (Input.GetKeyUp(KeyCode.R))
        {
            var lookPos = transform.position + objectToScale.transform.position;
            lookPos.y = 0;
            var rotation = Quaternion.LookRotation(lookPos);
            objectToScale.transform.rotation = Quaternion.Slerp(objectToScale.transform.rotation, rotation, Time.deltaTime * damping);
        }
}
```

I want that when I release the R key that the object will rotate facing another object.

It will work if I will remove the rotating back part out of the GetKeyUp. But then it will keep rotating  the object all the time and I want it to rotate back only when I release the R key but it's not working.

This is what I mean the rotating back part:

```
if (Input.GetKeyUp(KeyCode.R))
            {
                var lookPos = transform.position + objectToScale.transform.position;
                lookPos.y = 0;
                var rotation = Quaternion.LookRotation(lookPos);
                objectToScale.transform.rotation = Quaternion.Slerp(objectToScale.transform.rotation, rotation, Time.deltaTime * damping);
            }
```

But nothing happen when I release the R key.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not the most elegant solution but it should illustrate my point.

If you wanted to lerp back to the original position, it needs to be called per update. So i just used a trigger.

You also need to minus the positions between the target and source to get the direction between each of them.

```
    public bool freeRotateTrigger = false;
    public Transform target;

    void Update()
    {
        if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.R))
            freeRotateTrigger = true; 

        if (Input.GetKeyUp(KeyCode.R))
            freeRotateTrigger = false;

        if (freeRotateTrigger)
        {
            transform.Rotate(Vector3.up, 50f * Time.deltaTime);
        }
        else
        {
            Vector3 relativePos = target.position - transform.position;
            Quaternion rotation = Quaternion.LookRotation(relativePos);
            transform.rotation = Quaternion.Slerp(transform.rotation, rotation, Time.deltaTime * 10f);
        }
    }
```